# reCAPTCHA message within the form: "This reCAPTCHA is currently running on localhost."

Tags: recaptcha

I am using **reCAPTCHA** on **localhost**. I already got my *site-key* and *secret-key*. Although almost everything works as expected, I get this message within the
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfa6R.png).

In the HTML I have only this row:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<Here I have put my site-key>"></div>
```

Does anyone know how to remove this message or the reason why this message appears?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see this as well. The message is probably just a warning and it only started to appear 1-2 days ago in my development environment. It doesn't appear in staging nor production.

I'm also pretty sure it doesn't affect the reCAPTCHA behaviour:
[Using reCAPTCHA on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232904/using-recaptcha-on-localhost)

Answer (score 2):

As another poster said, looks like google just added this when running locally.  If you really hate seeing it, you can override the .rc-anchor-alert class to display:none.

Answer (score 0):

its about time! I wasted so much time solving reCAPTCHA challenges on localhost when testing form submission