# WAMP localhost server and recaptcha not working

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, recaptcha

I'm using WAMP localhost (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and cant get recaptcha to work at all..

And I've tried it a ton its not that I'm doing the reCAPTCHA wrong.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer. It might be related to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/39154726/3097877

Comment: This has nothing to do with using WAMPServer

Comment: did you try adding: 

localhost/folderOfProjectHere/ 

to list of allowed domains? (if applicable)

Comment: It gives me "URL must not end with a path". This is so weird it works fine on dev / production.. maybe something to do with a firewall lol idk..

Comment: I have a hunch its a php.ini setting or something like that..