# Captcha MVC for ASP.Net MVC 4 with documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, captcha

I am looking for a simple Captcha MVC for ASP.Net MVC 4.
Most I've found has lack of **documentation**.
I tried to use Vyacheslav's Captcha MVC but it has bugs and lack of documentation (image disappears after click refresh, for example).
I also tried SuperCaptcha and I discarded it by the same reasons.
I discarded PiJiang's EasyCaptcha by the same reasons.
The same with BotDetect.

I also tried Google Recaptcha, but it asks to use the captcha in a production environment, and I want to test the captcha first in localhost.
Any ideas about a good and simple captcha with good documentation?

Comment: This could be of help with local reCaptcha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232904/using-recaptcha-on-localhost

Answer (score 3):

Try the following resources

- [Implement Different Types Of Captcha With ASP.NET MVC Using NuGet CaptchaMvc.Mvc5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-different-type-of-captchamvc-mvc5-with-asp-net-mvc-using-nuget-captcha/)
- [How to Implement CAPTCHA in ASP.Net MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd8b0b/how-to-implement-captcha-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)
- [Captcha Code Implementation in MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/781675/Captcha-Code-Implementation-in-MVC)

hope this will help you