# ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key

Tags: python, scrapy

Im trying to scrape some images with the help of Scrapy,

after i have fetched the site,and type in the command `view response`,
A window opens in my browser like it should,but instead of the photos and details being shown, i get the captcha error`ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key`.

What am i supposed to do get around this!,any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

The [link](http://data.desmoinesregister.com/iowa-mugshots/?co=Polk) of the website.

The screenshot of the error is also posted below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This error may occur due to several reasons... here I list some possible causes of this error...** 
 
**1]** It could be a reCAPTCHA API/site key issue, The site key is used to invoke the reCAPTCHA service on the website. If this is the case then

> *This error is not for you, this is for the website owner*.

This issue usually occurs when the API user uses the same site key (registered for a particular domain) on multiple domains. And I don't think that the issue will persist, it would be a temporary issue. 
 
 
**2]** Maybe you trying to open the reCAPTCHA from a file:// or on localhost. 
 
 
**3]** Maybe the **referer-header** in **HTTP Request** is not set properly. 
 
 
**4]** Maybe you trying to solve a reCAPTCHA by grabbing captcha images. 

 
 I hope this (answer) helps you.

Comment: Thank you for you time, will check this out

Comment: @aravind Yes,  it is. For more details visit https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation or check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232904/using-recaptcha-on-localhost