# ReCaptcha is blokking my Wordpress login access in Localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not able to login, so I can't disable the plugin from the WordPress dashboard.
-I tried already move the plugin folder to another location from the WordPress installation → wp-content → plugins and move the contact-form-7, wordfenses en Captcha folders.

- also tried to generate a new key to my localhost wp-admin.
  But also Don't WORK.
  Message: "Localhost is not in the list of supported domains for this site key"

Anybody here can help me?  (I'm a beginner developer ;])
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using reCAPTCHA on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232904/using-recaptcha-on-localhost)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get rid of the captcha block then a very easy way to do that is to just **rename the plugin file**. And the next time you reload the page the plugin will get automatically deactivated.

So, `plugin-name` becomes `plugin-name-bak`.