# Flutter web : I am getting 403 permission denied error after implementing Firebase app check

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, firebase-app-check

## [Flutter Firebase - App Check](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/overview)

### Flutter Web

Before hand, I uploaded the images to bucket manually.
I need help to fetch the data from firebase storage bucket.

- I was trying to fetch images stored as jpeg format in 1920x1080p resolution.

  ```
  Future<String> imageData = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('images')
      .child('panda_16x9.jpeg')
      .getDownloadURL();
  ```
- Then i am passing **imageData** to **FutureBuilder**

  ```
  FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: imageData,
  builder: (context, imageUrl) {
    if(imageUrl.hasError) {
      return __(widget saying error)__
    }
    if(imageUrl.hasData) {
      return Image.network(imageUrl.data!);
    }
    return __(loading widget)__
  });
  ```
- I also tried getting data is Uint8List but no success because the main issue is **Permission Denied from server**

### Issues

1. initially was getting cors error

   - no "access-control-origin-access" on the Request Response header.
   - fixed it by going to GCP and opening the cloud shell and adding the cors rules.

   > - Open Google Cloud Console
   > - Select the project same as firebase project
   > - open the cloud shell
   > - The create a file `touch cors.json`
   > - use vim to edit `vim cors.json`
   >
   > ```
   > [
   >  {
   >   "origin":["*"], // In production we will replace it with original domain name
   >   "method":["GET","POST","UPDATE","DELETE"],
   >   "header":["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
   >   "maxAgeSeconds":3600,
   >  }
   > ]
   > ```
   >
   > - run command `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-bucker>`
   >
   > > You can find the bucket url from firebase storage section
2. After i fixed the cors issue, i starting getting Invalid App Check token

   - It was an easy fix. Just needed to follow as per [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/overview)
   - I am now getting error **"Permission Denied" 403 Status Code**

| App check invalid token is gone | but, getting Permission Denied 403 Error Code |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? Can your share any image or link of your expected result?

Comment: Can you clarify the question by including `DescriptionCard` and what is `media`?

Comment: `'Part A', width: media.size.width,` is already having maxwidth, rebuild the app, it will fix the UI view and share the issue

Comment: please check the question, that is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Does your rules on Firebase Storage allow you to access the resource?. Does it require login?, does the default time to access it has been reached?, etc.

Comment: Have you added recaptcha-v3-site-key in code?
```await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key');```

Where 'recaptcha-v3-site-key' should be replaced with your key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned if you set up [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha) or configured WebApp in your Firebase project.

### Register your website for reCAPTCHA

You can register your website on the [Admin page](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create). If you want to develop your website locally, you need to visit `127.0.0.1` or add localhost to the domains. See [Using reCAPTCHA on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987136/7365866).

### Then, configure the app in your firebase project.

Go to **Project Settings** > **App Check** > And add the `reCAPTCHA` secret key.

[image: Firebase project settings page]

Then enter the key:
[image]

Once App Check is configured correctly, then storage could potentially work.