# invisible recaptcha api js blocked me

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, content-security-policy, invisible-recaptcha

I've try to use v2 invisible Recaptcha and CSC blocking reCaptcha as you see in my picture and i tried add `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha`  Content-Security-Policy to my web config but it is still not working. Where is the my Problem.Thanks for taking a look.

[image]

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Comment: Might be because you're running it on localhost. Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987136

Comment: Problem is solved sir when i add https://www.google.com/ https://www.gstatic.com/ to my web config Content-Security-Policy. Thanks