# react-google-recaptcha doesn't appear on localhost with nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, recaptcha

I'm trying to integrate ReCAPTCHA to secure emails on my website.
Thing is: it doesn't appear at all, but throws no errors.

I'm using ReCAPTHA V2 with tickbox (note that I'd like to have a simple tickbox and not the "click on all the light bulbs" challenge). The key given is the **site key**.

I'm on a NextJS 13+ project running on localhost for now.

`localhost` has been registered as an authorized domain within my recaptcha settings.

Accessing localhost with `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` and putting `127.0.0.1` in authorized domains like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232904/using-recaptcha-on-localhost) does not solve the issue.

```js
import {ReCAPTCHA} from "react-google-recaptcha";

const recaptchaKey=process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_KEY

//...

<form>
  <ReCAPTCHA sitekey={recaptchaKey} />
</form>
```